# Putting SDL surfaces in a map, along with file names

Tags: c++, dictionary, sdl, surface, stdmap

I'm very new to using maps in C++, so I am having some difficulties using it for my SDL surfaces. This is what I've tried (not working):

```
map <SDL_Surface*, char*> mSurfaceMap;

mSurfaceMap.insert(pair<SDL_Surface*, char*>(m_poSurfaceTest, "..//..//gfx//testImage.png"));
```

The idea is to put all surfaces and their corresponding image files in a map to easily initialize them and do `IMG_Load()` on them, as well as free them when closing the program.

If this is a bad solution for it, please point me in the right direction. I first thought of making two arrays, but I wanted to try this instead, as I felt it was a more elegant solution. If the solution is ok, I'd love to hear what I am doing wrong in the code.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the error that you are receiving.  Is it a compile-time error or a run-time error?

Comment: Compile error. There's many, but mostly duplicates:    

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    
error C2371: 'mSurfaceMap' : redefinition; different basic types

Comment: Avoid storing literal strings as `char*`. While strictly allowed (thanks C), attempting to modify such a string will likely cause a crash (certainly does on linux/g++).

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` is great for looking up data by an ordered key, it is usually implemented as a balanced binary tree that gives O(log n) look-up time. If the look-up order doesn't matter then a `std::hash_map` will be a better choice with an O(1) look-up time.

The problem with using a pointer as your key in either container is that the they will index by the integer address of the pointer, not the value of what is pointed to.

`std::string`, however, has value semantics and implements the less-than operator which will let the container index by the value of the string.

You may also want to put your surface in a smart pointer for memory management purposes.

```
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> surface_pointer;
typedef pair<std::string, surface_pointer > surface_pair;

std::map<std::string, surface_pointer > mSurfaceMap;

mSurfaceMap.insert(surface_pair("..//..//gfx//testImage.png", surface_pointer(m_poSurfaceTest)));
```

A couple of other thoughts...

If you don't need the look-up functionality, and are just using a container for housekeeping, then a simple `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, SDL_Surface*> >` would probably suffice for what you need.

Or, if you're storing the surfaces as members already (assuming from the variable name) then you could store the member variables as a `tr1::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface>` and when the containing class is deleted so will the `SDL_Surface` be deleted. For this to work however you need to provide a custom deallocator for the `tr1::unique_ptr`, that will teach it how to free an `SDL_Surface*`.

```
struct SdlSurfaceDeleter {
    void operator() (SDL_Surface*& surface) {
        if (surface) {
            SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
            surface = NULL;
        }
    }
};
```

Then you would specify your members like this (a typedef makes it less verbose):

```
typedef std::tr1::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, SdlSurfaceDeleter> surface_ptr;

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(const std::string& path)
        : m_poSurfaceTest(IMG_Load(path.c_str()) { }

    surface_ptr m_poSurfaceTest;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.  Output is as expected:

```
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>

using std::map;
using std::pair;

struct Custom
{
    int val;
    Custom() {val=0;}
};

int main(int argC,char* argV[]) 
{
    map<Custom*,char*> mMap;
    Custom* test = new Custom;
    mMap.insert(pair<Custom*,char*>(test,"Test"));
    printf("%s\n",mMap[test]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But perhaps this isn't what you actually want.  A map provides a one-way mapping from some key (in your case, an SDL surface pointer) to some other thing.  For what you want, perhaps it's more appropriate to use a single array of pairs.

Comment: Array of pairs, I didn't think of that. Smart!